# Not able load '\' character in mysql db

Tags: mysql, csv

I am not able to load '\' character from CSV file into mysql db version 6.1

Suppose below is my excel table converted to CSV.

```
------------------------------
ColumnHeader1 | ColumnHeader2 |
------------------------------
BA\           |Pune           |
-------------------------------
```

Mysql command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\mydatafile.csv' 
INTO TABLE mydb.mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(ColumnHeader1,ColumnHeader2);
```

when I run the `select` query in above table, I got below output which is not similar to above table. This was working perfect in mysql 6.1. Now upgraded to 6.2 created problem.

```
------------------------------
ColumnHeader1 | ColumnHeader2 |
------------------------------
BAPune           |null        |
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing all of your \ with \\ on the csv file and see what happens

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Backslash is the MySQL escape character within strings in SQL statements, so to specify a literal backslash, you must specify two backslashes for the value to be interpreted as a single backslash. The escape sequences '\t' and '\n' specify tab and newline characters, respectively.

Comment: its not possilbe for me to replay in all 500000 records in different cells. And again it worked perfect in 6.1 version.

Comment: how so? it's just a text file perl -pi -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' mydatafile.csv

Comment: Yes replacing all my '\' in data with '\\' and adding ESCAPED BY '\\' worked for me.

Comment: then accept the solution given, it's just a click away

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'` in your query like

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\mydatafile.csv' 
INTO TABLE mydb.mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(ColumnHeader1,ColumnHeader2);
```

Comment: It didn't worked. Seem I have to downgrade mysql from 6.2 to 6.1 which was perfectly working with same data and sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Your `\` is not escaped by mysql, you need to escape it to have it in your database.
You'll have two choices to do that if you want to only use either your hand or mysql only: Either replace *by hand* (which is a poor man's way) `\` into `\\`;

Or you could use `LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE 'escape_character' ]` [in an insert statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php), thus allowing you to escape everything you'd like.